# vegalite in sweeve in R

Tags: r, rstudio, knitr, vega-lite

I am trying to use vegalite to display some plots in sweeve/knitr  but all I get is a white space with no plot in there.

My code follows, it is based on a tutorial example:

````
---
title: "VegaLite test"
output: html_notebook
---

```{r}
library(vegalite)
library(magrittr)    
```

```{r barplot, fig.width=8, fig.height=6}

dat <- jsonlite::fromJSON('[
    {"a": "A","b": 28}, {"a": "B","b": 55}, {"a": "C","b": 43},
    {"a": "D","b": 91}, {"a": "E","b": 81}, {"a": "F","b": 53},
    {"a": "G","b": 19}, {"a": "H","b": 87}, {"a": "I","b": 52}
  ]')

vegalite() %>%
  add_data(dat) %>%
  encode_x("a", "ordinal") %>%
  encode_y("b", "quantitative") %>%
  mark_bar() -> vl

vl
```
````

I am using:

```
> packageVersion("vegalite")
[1] ‘0.7.1’
> packageVersion("magrittr")
[1] ‘1.5’    
> packageVersion("knitr")
[1] ‘1.15.1’

RStudio: Version 1.0.136 

> R.version
               _                           
platform       x86_64-w64-mingw32          
arch           x86_64                      
os             mingw32                     
system         x86_64, mingw32             
status                                     
major          3                           
minor          3.3                         
year           2017                        
month          03                          
day            06                          
svn rev        72310                       
language       R                           
version.string R version 3.3.3 (2017-03-06)
nickname       Another Canoe
```

I am wondering what I should do to see the data displayed correctly

Answer (score 0):

I have tried your example and it was striking that the plot appears in the viewer panel and not in the plot panel. So, add `runtime: shiny` to your YAML header:

```
---
title: "VegaLite test"
output: html_notebook
runtime: shiny
---
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion,  but it still does not work, .... and I do not see any error anywhere.  The good thing is that if I click on "run document" the whole document comes out correct.

Comment: Nope, I am using the latest version.  By any chance,  do you have the same problem?  I am thinking to post a bug report to the vegalite developers.

Comment: Then it is something strange in my environment  Thanks.  I will try to reinstall everything.